# Sistema de coordenadas incorrecto al visualizar imagen usando PyQtGraph

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente imagen de prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el siguiente script de Python para poder visualizarla usando el paquete PyQtGraph:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
img = Image.open('mickey.tif')
a = np.array(img)
pg.image(a)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Al correr el script, el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde se puede apreciar que el arreglo de NumPy que contiene la matriz de la imagen es interpretado por PyQtGraph según un sistema de coordenadas invertido respecto al usado por programas habituales para manejo de imágenes: visor del SO, motores de navegación web; incluso Matlab, donde se interpreta la matriz NumPy de forma correcta.

Una solución consiste en visualizar el arreglo transpuesto, usando `pg.image(a.T)`, pero esto solo será útil si la imagen es de un solo canal, ya que una imagen de más canales (RGB, por ejemplo) solo pasa un canal a la función `pg.image()`, dando como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es la forma correcta, o más adecuada, de obtener el sistema de coordenadas deseado? He buscado en la documentación y no encuentro algo útil. Supongo que utilizar la transpuesta puede complicar la extracción de información de la imagen: como coordenadas a partir de una ROI, valores de píxeles y sus coordenadas.

Comment: Te sirve si rotas la imágen con img.rotate antes de convertirla en un ndarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la creación del `ImageView` le puedes pasar un argumento `transform` que indique cómo transformar el sistema de coordenadas. Este argumento es del tipo `Transform3D`.

No he probado a ver si funciona, pero el código tendría que ser algo parecido a ésto:

```
# rotación de 90 grados alrededor del origen (0,0,0)
tr = pg.Transform3D()
tr.rotate(90, 0, 0, 0)

pg.image(a, transform=tr)
```

Ya me dirás si funciona.

---

**CORRECCIÓN**: El método `transform` de la clase `ImageView` requiere que el argumento sea `QTransform`. El código anterior corregido sería.

```
# rotación de 90 grados alrededor del origen (0,0,0)
tr = pg.QtGui.QTransform()
tr.rotate(90)

pg.image(a, transform=tr)
```

Comment: Arroja este error: `TypeError: QGraphicsItem.setTransform(QTransform, bool combine=False): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Transform3D'`.

Comment: Lo que te dice es que espera un `QTransform` en lugar de `Transform3D`: `tr = pg.QtGui.QTransform(); tr.rotate(90)`.

Comment: Funciona. ¿Podrías editar la respuesta?

Comment: Ya he añadido una corrección.

Answer (score 0):

Y no te sirve simplemente rotar la imagen antes de convertirla en un `ndarray`?, es decir:

```
a = np.array(img.rotate(90))
```

Comment: No. La idea no es solo visualizar, y buscaba una solución tipo configuración que permitiera a `pyqtgraph` interpretar las coordenadas de la imagen como lo hace `Qt` y no con su propio sistema de coordenadas rotado.